# What is this white stuff on my magnolia leaves and can it be cured?

Tags: diagnosis

I'm a total amateur and not sure what is wrong with our magnolia plant. Here is a picture of white stuff that is on both sides of many of the leaves: [image: white stuff on both sides of leaves]

Any ideas on what this is and how/if we can cure it?

EDIT - Additional pictures

The plant overall is about 6.5 feet tall: [image: pot]

Stem closeup: [image: stem]

Closeup of leaf: [image: closeup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its Magnolia scale - the stems are out of focus in the image, but there might possibly be adult hard scales on there, as well as the crawlers on the leaves. Plants which are stressed are more likely to be infested; your magnolia does not look in very good condition and needs either a larger pot or transferring to the ground so it can produce more growth. You can wipe off the white crawlers with a cloth, otherwise use Neem spray or horticultural oil spray, further information here https://www.mortonarb.org/trees-plants/tree-and-plant-advice/help-pests/magnolia-scale-neolecanium-cornuparvum

Comment: It has quite a large pot that we moved it into about 6 months ago. Also, I don't notice anything on the stems like in that link. I'll try to get some more pictures if it will help further identity the issue - or do you think that it is 100%?

Comment: I can't see the whole pot, but judging by the bit I can see, unless its very deep, it likely isn't large enough - either that or its lost a lot of foliage for another reason. 90% sure its probaby magnolia scale - have a look at the white areas with a magnifying glass, you should see creatures in amongst the fluff if it is.

Comment: I added some additional photos.  There does appear to be some small amount of the white stuff on the stems, but it doesn't seem to match with the stem photo from the link you posted. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The image in that link just shows the adult form of the scale - not seeing those on your plant yet, just the juvenile form, which suggests the obvious leaf loss and ladck of growth is down to not enough root room. . I'd treat for scale as suggested, but your plant needs a pot probably twice the size of the one its currently in - either that or a pot that's not necessarily wider, but much deeper, 2 feet deep if possible.